# Where should I put the csv test file in PyTorch dataloader?

Tags: pytorch

Let say  I have test.csv

```
   filename
1  a.jpg

2  b.jpb
```

then I have test image folder 
/test

```
test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root= path + 'test/',transform=trans)
```

this will bring all the test files

If I want to make a submission file after done training, how should I link test folder's name and submission.csv file name?

```
%%time
from torch.autograd import Variable
results = []
with torch.no_grad():
    model.eval()
    print('start')
    for num, data in enumerate(test_loader):
        #print(num)
        imgs, label = data
        imgs,labels = imgs.to(device), label.to(device)
        test = Variable(imgs)
        output = model(test)
        ps = torch.exp(output)
        top_p, top_class = ps.topk(1, dim = 1)
        #print(top_class)
        results += top_class.cpu().numpy().tolist()


predictions = np.array(results).flatten()
```

> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0,
>          1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
>          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>          1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
>          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>          0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>          0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>          1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>          0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

How should I know which result is from which file?

Comment: It will be synchronize to `testloader`. First array value for first image and second value array for second image so on

Comment: then you can save it as dataframe column like `df['predictions'] = predictions`